# What is the "imgcount.txt" file in every one of my My Pictures subfolders in Windows 7 64-bit Prof? Why? Delete?

Tags: photos

I have almost 280 different imgcount.txt files, one in each subfolder of My Pictures folder in Windows 7. Each with just a number of how many files are in each folder.

Is it because of my iPhone syncing? Or Fireworks? Photoshop? Screen saver?

Why do they exist and how useful are they? Can I delete them?

Comment: do you have a image management softwrae such a Google Picasa or Adobe Lightroom installed?

I am also using Win7 64Bit and it doesn't happen to me.

Comment: Fireworks, photoshop, and photo gallery screen-saver don't do this for me.  I don't have an iphone.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an application installed that isn't aware of the existence of the 'appData' folder in Windows 7. You should just leave them there if you don't want that piece of software to fail because of a lack of data. You could delete them, but I'm sure they'll eventually come back if you keep using the particular piece of software.